# Creating an image in jQuery and adding to DOM after load

Tags: jquery, image, onload

I have a function that creates an image object. I give the image a src and then I add a load function that adds the image to the DOM once loaded. It works except it's always adding 2 instances of the image to the page and I can't figure out why. Can someone tell me why this adds two images to my page?

```
var img = new Image();

$(img).load(function () {               
    $('#imageContainter').append(this);
    $(this).fadeIn();
})              
.error(function () {
    // notify the user that the image could not be loaded
})              
.attr('src', '' + _filename);
```

"_filename" is the source path and "imageContainer" is the div that I load the image into.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you stepped through it in FireFox firebug or Chrome dev tools to see if it is getting called more than once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(new Image()).attr('src', '' + _filename).appendTo($('#imageContainter')).fadeIn();
```

Then if the 'error' part is important you can check the src or something.

I would also recommend using show() instead of fadeIn() if you're not supplying any fade time

Comment: My guess would be that when you append the new DOM element the load method executes because the new element is loaded and when you supply a new source it executes again cause of the new image source.